# updating permanent db using in-memory db

Tags: sqlite

How can I update a big permanent database by a small in-memory database? I have an application that has a big permanent db(on hard disk) and small in-memory db(in RAM). During run time of my application in-memory database is filled up and at the end of the run it updates permanent db.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this with ATTACH DATABASE:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html

**EDIT 05.12.2011:**

Here I create an on-disk database:

```
[someone@localhost ~]$ sqlite3 some_big_db
SQLite version 3.7.5
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> create table t1 (a int, b text);
```

Here I open an in-memory database, create a table, populate it, attach the on-disk database, and copy the in-memory database table's content in the on-disk database table:

```
[someone@localhost ~]$ sqlite3 
SQLite version 3.7.5
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> create table t2 (a int, b text);
sqlite> insert into t2 values (1, 'aa');
sqlite> insert into t2 values (2, 'bb');
sqlite> attach database some_big_db as big_db;
sqlite> insert into t1 select * from t2;
```

Here I open the on-disk database and select its table's content:

```
[someone@localhost ~]$ sqlite3 some_big_db 
SQLite version 3.7.5
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> select * from t1;
1|aa
2|bb
```

Comment: thanks sixfeetsix for response. Can you please bring an example(some code will help alot). P.S. sorry I am new to SQL

Comment: @user1079655: I added some code demonstrating how one can use attach database to achieve what you asked for.